# How to remove the top bar from flutter date picker

Tags: flutter, datepicker

[image: Default flutter date picker]

So, basically I want to completely remove the top bar in bluish color which shows the current date and year and start the calendar interface from the white background but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flutter is an open source project which allows you to modify their entire code.

You should take a look at the class `_DatePickerDialog` and `_DatePickerHeader`.

Copy the entire code from **`date_picker.dart`** and, at line 1020, remove **header** and that's it.

```
         return Container(
            color: theme.dialogBackgroundColor,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                header, // this one is the header
                Flexible(child: picker),
                actions,
              ],
            ),
          )
```

Most likely you should change **Flexible** for **Expanded** over your **Column**.

Here is the official docs [**showDatePicker**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html)